# How to Partition the FvwmButtons

Tags: window-manager, window-management, window-decorations, fvwm

I've read some *.fvwm2rc* but I still want to know how we partition the `FvwmButtons` in Fvwm. How can we assign a specific slice to `Swallow` specific application?